# C++ selectively overloading [ ]?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, operator-overloading, overloading, abstraction

Given:

```
class example
{
    public:
        std::vector<std::vector<int>> a;
        int b;
}

func()
{
    example e;
    ... // populate e
```

I could then use examples members like so.

```
    int n = e.b;
    int n2 = e.a[2][3];
```

However, could I alternatively override the [ ] operator such that.

```
    int n = e.b;
    int n2 = e[2][3];
}
```

?

edit: Sorry, the example is now fixed.

Comment: I don't see any `[]` in your code...

Comment: Where is your need for overloading? I've dont see any `[]` needing.

Comment: Was that last block supposed to be different somehow?

Comment: @MichaelWilson it is, it lacks the `.a`.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1971207/14065

Comment: I am not sure what the down votes are for. Seems like a valid question.

Comment: @Loki : The downvotes were probably pre-edit, when the question had no relation to `operator[]`.

Comment: -1 for drastically changing the question. @LokiAstari see the revision history.

Comment: Sorry, I suck reguarding the edit, especially to the person who had just answered, this is the question I meant to ask though :¬P and it has a great answer by Christian Rau.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you could do is overload the access operator and delegate it to the vector:

```
class example
{
    public:
        std::vector<std::vector<int>> a;
        int b;

        const std::vector<int>& operator[](std::size_t i) const
        {
            return a[i];
        }
        std::vector<int>& operator[](std::size_t i)
        {
            return a[i];
        }
};
```

The first `[]` will then return a reference to `a`'s respective element, on which the second `[]` will be used.

Answer (score 2):

One naive solution would be to define your own `operator[]`:

```
class example
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> v;
public:
    std::vector<int> const & operator[](std::size_t i) const { return v[i]; }
    std::vector<int>       & operator[](std::size_t i)       { return v[i]; }

    // ...
};
```

Now if you have `example e;`, then `e[1]` is a vector of ints, etc.

It looks like you want to write some matrix class, though. For that, it's more efficient to have just a single vector and access it in strides:

```
class Matrix
{
    std::size_t cols;
    std::size_t rows;
    std::vector<int> v;

public:
    explicit Matrix(std::size_t r, std::size_t c) : cols(c), rows(r), v(r*c) { }

    int operator()(std::size_t i, std::size_t j) const { return v[i * cols + j]; }
    int & operator()(std::size_t i, std::size_t j) { return v[i * cols + j]; }
};
```

Now you can say: `Matrix m(4, 7); m(1, 3) = 8;`. You have to use the round-bracket operator for that, since the square-bracket operator must always take exactly *one* argument and thus isn't suitable here.