# Overload = operator for class that shall behave like matrix

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, overloading

I've got a template of a class that shall behave like matrix.
So the usecase is something like:

```
Matrix matrix(10,10);
matrix[0][0]=4;
//set the values for the rest of the matrix
cout<<matrix[1][2]<<endl;
```

When I set the values directly in the constructor, it works well, but when I want to use `matrix[x][y]=z;` I get `error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment`. I assume, that I must overload `=` operator. Nevertheless I tried whole evening and I didn't find out, how to implement it. Would anybody be please so kind and show me how to overload `=` operator for my code, to make it assign values to that matrix?

code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

class Matrix {
public:

    Matrix(int x,int y) {
        _arrayofarrays = new int*[x];
        for (int i = 0; i < x; ++i)
            _arrayofarrays[i] = new int[y];

        // works here
        _arrayofarrays[3][4] = 5;
    }

    class Proxy {
    public:

        Proxy(int* _array) : _array(_array) {
        }

        int operator[](int index) {
            return _array[index];
        }
    private:
        int* _array;
    };

    Proxy operator[](int index) {
        return Proxy(_arrayofarrays[index]);
    }

private:
    int** _arrayofarrays;
};

int main() {
    Matrix matrix(5,5);

    // doesn't work :-S
    // matrix[2][1]=0;

    cout << matrix[3][4] << endl;
}
```

Comment: What did you try for your operator= overload?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1971201/how-to-overload-array-index-operator-for-wrapper-class-of-2d-array

Comment: What type does `matrix[1][2]` yield?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you intend to modify the element of the matrix referenced by the proxy, then the overload of `operator[]` in the `Proxy` class must return a reference:

```
int& operator[](int index)
```

At the moment, you return `int`, which makes a copy of the element’s value—not what you want. There ought to be a `const` overload as well, so that `operator[]` works on `const` matrices. This one can return by value:

```
int operator[](int index) const
```

And actually, `size_t` would be more appropriate for the index than `int`, since it’s an unsigned type. You aren’t giving any particular meaning to negative indices, so it makes sense to disallow them.

You don’t need to overload `operator=` of `Proxy` unless you want to assign a whole row at once. In fact, you don’t need the `Proxy` class at all, because you can just return a pointer to the row array directly. However, if you want to change your design—e.g., using a sparse or packed representation—then the `Proxy` would let you keep the `m[i][j]` interface.

Comment: That said, the entire `Proxy` object doesn't seem to be needed at all anymore.

Comment: uh...TY...It seems,that I tried to hunt sparrows with a cannon and didn't notice, that I can do it this way :)

Comment: @DrewDormann: Right, thanks. I added a note about that.

Comment: You also might want the Proxy if you don't want your rows to have other unwelcome pointer behavior.  Like subtraction.

Comment: Another problem, now really (I hope :)) with overloading the `=` operator appeared..Wouldn't you mind to spend a minute to take a look on it pls?

Comment: @Dworza: That's a seperate question. Make another post.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that you're returning an int value in proxy::operator[]. Your first [] operator returns the proxy object, the second returns an int. If your proxy [] operator were to return an int reference, then you would be able to assign to it:

```
int& operator[](int index) {
    return _array[index];
}
```