# Deep copy of a matrix-like class

Tags: c++, pointers, operator-overloading, overloading

I've got a class that shall behave like matrix.
So the usecase is something like:

```
Matrix matrix(10,10);
matrix[0][0]=4;
//set the values for the rest of the matrix
cout<<matrix[1][2]<<endl;
```

code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

class Matrix {
public:


    Matrix(int x, int y);

    class Proxy {
    public:

        Proxy(int* _array) : _array(_array) {
        }

        int &operator[](int index) const {
            return _array[index];
        }
    private:
        int* _array;
    };

   Proxy operator[](int index) const {
      return Proxy(_arrayofarrays[index]);
   }
   Proxy operator[](int index) {
      return Proxy(_arrayofarrays[index]);
   }

    const Matrix& operator=(const Matrix& othersales);

private:
    int** _arrayofarrays;
    int x, y;
};

Matrix::Matrix(int x, int y) {
    _arrayofarrays = new int*[x];
    for (int i = 0; i < x; ++i)
        _arrayofarrays[i] = new int[y];
}

const Matrix& Matrix::operator=(const Matrix& othermatrix) {
    new (this) Matrix(x, y);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            _arrayofarrays[i][j] = othermatrix._arrayofarrays[i][j];

    return *this;
}

int main() {

    Matrix a(2, 3);
    a[0][0] = 1;
    a[0][1] = 2;
    a[0][2] = 3;
    a[1][0] = 4;
    a[1][1] = 5;
    a[1][2] = 6;

    cout << a[1][2] << endl;
    //prints out 6


    const Matrix b = a;
    cout << b[1][2] << endl;

    a[1][2] = 3;

    cout << a[1][2] << endl;
    // prints out 3
    cout << b[1][2] << endl;
    // prints out 3 as well
}
```

By calling `const Matrix b = a;` I want to create new instance of Matrix, that will have the same values as `a` has in that moment. Nevertheless `b` is being affected by changing the values in `a`. So if I change some value in `a`, then it changes in `b` as well. And I don't want it to behave like this.

So I need to create a copy of `b` that would not be affected by `a` itself.

Those might be stupid question, but for me, as a java guy and a C++ newbie are all those stuff really confusing, so thanks for any helpful advices...

Comment: Check the [answer from your last question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15753838/16287) again.  You need `operator[](int index)` for non-const objects ***and*** `operator[](int index) const` for const objects.  You only have one of those.

Comment: you cannot declare an object as constant

Comment: @DrewDormann You're right, I forgot to implement this. I'll edit my post. Nevertheless, the values are still being affected by the changes on the original object.

Comment: @Dworza No problem - go ahead and update your question.  Be sure to compile the code before posting it.

Comment: @Dworza Can you update you question so it's clear what question you're asking?  I don't know what you're asking anymore.

Comment: ah..sorry...I see, that I made some mistakes there.. Excuse me pls..it's already 3:30 AM here :] Is it clearer now?

Comment: @Dworza The problem you describe isn't real.  You're **copying** values to `b`.  They won't be affected by later changes to `a`.

Comment: @DrewDormann I've realized, that `const Matrix& Matrix::operator=(const Matrix& othermatrix)`  isn't called at all, so there might be the problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with your implementation. The simple one is the error you are getting...

In your `Matrix` class, `operator[]` is a non-const member function, which means that it can only be executed on non-const objects. Your `operator=` takes the right hand side object by `const &`, and thus you cannot call `operator[]` on it. The issue here is that you are not offering an implementation of `operator[]` that promises not to modify the object, once you add that to your type it should compile.

More important than that is the fact that you are leaking memory. When you call `operator=` on an object you are creating a different `Matrix` in place, without previously releasing the memory that it held. That is a memory leak.

The implementation of `operator=` is also not thread-safe. If allocation of memory for any of the internal arrays fails and throws an exception you are leaving your object in a state that is neither the original one nor a valid state. This is bad in itself.

Related to the previous, in as much as correcting one probably leads to the other, your implementation of `operator=` is not safe if there is *aliasing*, that is, it fails if you self-assign. The first line will leak the memory and create the new buffers, and from there on you will copy the new buffer into itself, loosing the original information.

Finally, the implementation of the type could be improved if you drop the requirement of using `operator[]` and use instead `operator()` with the two indices. User code will have to be adapted (and look less like a bidimensional array) but it provides a bit more freedom of representation (you can store the information internally in any way you want). At the same time, there is no need to allocate an array of pointers and then N arrays of `int`. You can perform a single memory allocation of NxM `ints` and do pointer arithmetic to address each location (this is independent of the use of `operator[]`/`operator()`), which will reduce the memory footprint and make the layout more compact, improving cache performance (not to mention reducing the number of dynamic allocations by a factor of M)

> By calling `const Matrix b = a;` I want to create new instance of Matrix, that will have the same values of a in that moment. Nevertheless b is being affected by changing the values in a.

Well, this is yet another issue I missed in the first read. The expression `const Matrix b = a;` does not involve `operator=`, but rather the copy constructor. Another thing to google: *Rule of the Three* (basically, if you implement one of copy-constructor, assignment or destructor manually, you probably want to implement all three). Without defining your own copy constructor the compiler will implicitly define one for you that does a shallow copy (i.e. copies the pointers stored in `Matrix` but does not allocate memory for it). After the copy is made both `Matrix` *share* the same memory, and if your destructor releases the memory, you will run into Undefined Behavior when the second destructor runs and tries to `delete []` the already deleted memory.

Comment: Thank you for your post and let me explain you, why I've implemented it the way I did. 1) I've edited my post to be able to handle `const` objects. 2) It's not the intention to make a copy and throw out the original without destroying it. It shall work just normal `=`, ie `int a,b; a=3; b=a;` ~~~> `b==3` ...next `a=4;` but still `b==3` , if you know, what I mean. 3) I can't use `()` because I'm trying solve my homework, where we have to use `[][]` indexing.

Comment: @Dworza: re. 2) I never assume that it is anyone's intention to leak memory, or to make the assignment unsafe under different conditions (self-assignment, exceptions), but it is a fact that the implementation in your class is not safe under those two circumstances, and it leaks memory. BTW, a common idiom to solve both issues is *copy-and-swap* (google it). The comments about the memory layout also stand, whether your interface uses `operator()` or `operator[]` you can still manage the memory internally in different ways.

Comment: @Dworza: Updated explaining why you see that behavior. You need to implement the copy-constructor.