# How can I invoke an overloaded () operator on the keyword this?

Tags: c++, oop, overloading

The following works but feels ugly when I do the `(*this)(5)` part.

```
struct MyStruct
{
    void operator()(int a)
    {
        // Do something with "a"
    }

    void myFunc()
    {
        (*this)(5);
    }
};
```

I will need to overload the `()` operator and use it from within other class methods.

Comment: `this` is a pointer, and [you can't overload the operators of pointer types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871039/how-to-overload-operator-for-a-pointer-to-the-class) as they are not user-defined. If this kind of aesthetic wart bothers you, C++ might not be the language for you. Similar things are all over the place. `this` rightly should be a reference rather than a pointer, but the feature was added to the language before references were.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I don't get your point. Nowhere is the OP trying to overload or call the operator for the pointer this. He is clearly calling the operator on `*this` which is not a pointer.

Comment: @bolov Right, so if that's sufficient, then there is *not a reproducible problem* here and the question should be closed. But I don't think that's the case. OP, by my reading, wishes *not* to have to dereference `this` in order to invoke the operator. Hence the complaint that the valid syntax `(*this)(5)` "feels ugly". The *reason* we have to write `*this`, so as to "call the operator on ... not a pointer", is that `this` is a pointer (as I said). Hence the `*`. To dereference the pointer, and thus get the non-pointer referent. Yeah?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I don't know why the OP thinks that is ugly, I can only presume and I try as much as possible not to presume. Anyway there are other options without explicitly dereferencing the pointer this.

Comment: Yes. But `Bhoo` for doing it. I would call you out in a code review for doing that. Make `operator()` call a named function. Then your code can also call a named function and be self documenting.

Comment: I'm not really experienced in C++ and I actively seek working solutions that are clean, not only working, hence the question. My real code is for a Matrix class, and I overload the `()` operator to do things like `A(2, 3) = 0.5` and so behind the `()` I convert the matrix indices 2 and 3 to a single index to obtain data from a 1D array. So having used calls like `A(2, 3) = ...` or `B(0, 1) = ...` to suddenly have to use a _seemingly_ odd `(*this)(4, 5) = ...` which didn't feel elegant.

Comment: `operator()(x,y) {return at(x,y);} myFunc(x,y) {return at(x,y);}` https://stackoverflow.com/a/1971207/14065

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have a few options:

- `(*this)(5)`
- `this->operator()(5)`
- or just `operator()(5)`
- Create a method that you call from within the `operator()`, e.g.:

  ```
  void do_work(int a) { /* ... */ }
  void operator()(int a) { do_work(a); }
  void myFunc() { do_work(5); }
  ```

Whichever you choose is just a matter of personal taste.

---

Just for fun, here are some  more (ridiculous) options:

- [`std::invoke`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke) (mentioned in comments):

  ```
  std::invoke(&MyStruct::operator(), this, 5);
  ```
- [`mem_fn`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn):

  ```
  auto call_op = std::mem_fn(&MyStruct::operator());
  call_op(this, 5);
  ```
- lambda:

  ```
  auto call_op = [this] (int a) { operator()(a); };
  call_op(5);
  ```
- [`bind_front`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind_front)

  ```
  auto call_op = std::bind_front(&MyStruct::operator(), this);
  call_op(5);
  ```

Comment: My personal vote is the fourth option. Use a named function for better self documenting code.

Comment: Restating because the numbers changed. My personal vote if for the named function that can be called as needed.